# Set new values on the url

Tags: php

I have a url which is showing two values posted using a GET method in php.
I can get the values from the url using this example -

suppose the url is **http://example.com/?name=Hannes**

*My code*

```
 <?php
    echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
    ?>
```

*And the output*  **Hello Hannes!**

My question is- how can I set the values to the url on button click method post
eg.

```
<form method="POST">
if(isset($_POST['$btn'){

 htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"])="Lucky";   /*If there is something like this*/

}
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
if(isset($_POST['$btn'){

    header('location:yourpage.php?name='.$yourValue);
    exit;   

}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution really helped me. #keepkookeeng